# Why does IPython execute code.py in the directory it's started in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

This is an update to the question below, because I've discovered the same thing happens when I start `bokeh_server` in a directory containing any script named `code.py`.

I have a directory, `/Users/xnx/temp/` containing many (mostly disposable) files including various scripts. When I start IPython from the command within my Anaconda `py33` virtual environment, it seems to run one of these scripts before dropping me into the IPython shell, because I get a list of the numbers and their cubes output to the screen before IPython shows its prompt:

```
Xnx-Mac:temp xnx$ py33
discarding /Users/xnx/anaconda/bin from PATH
prepending /Users/xnx/anaconda/envs/py33/bin to PATH
(py33)Xnx-Mac:temp xnx$ ipython
0
0
1
1
2
8
...
99
970299
Python 3.3.5 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (x86_64)| (default, Sep  2 2014, 13:57:31) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
```

(`py33` is just a bash alias for `source activate py33`).

This doesn't seem to be causing any harm, but I'd like to know why it's happening. Any ideas?

EDIT: OK: the offending script is a file called `code.py` in my `/Users/xnx/temp/` directory. Why is IPython executing this file before starting its shell? What if it had contained commands deleting files from my system? Can anyone else reproduce this? It doesn't seem to happen for Python 2.

Comment: What other bash aliases are set?

Comment: None of note... but see my edit.

Comment: look for an environmental variable `PYTHON_STARTUP` (I think) ... print `env` right before you start ipython

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, with a little (lot of) [help](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/23255726#23255726) from chat.stackoverflow.com, I've tracked down the problem:
My `~/.bash_profile` file contained the line

```
export PYTHONPATH="/Users/xnx/research/python_modules:$PYTHONPATH"
```

which set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` to `/Users/xnx/research/python_modules:` since `$PYTHONPATH` was not previously defined. The trailing colon leads to `''` being added to `sys.path`, and the current working directory gets searched for the file `code.py` before the correct one in an IPython `import` on start-up.

Lesson learned: don't let `$PYTHONPATH` have a trailing colon.